# SOQL query for related child information

Tags: soql, query

I'm trying to build a SOQL query to show the Name, Services and Contacts for accounts that have a relationship to a particular custom object, but I feel I'm missing something here:

```
SELECT Name, ServiceAccountAssociation__r.Name,
       Account.Contact.Name 
  FROM Account 
 WHERE ((Id IN (Select Account__c.Id from ServiceAccountAssociation__c)) 
   AND (BillingState = 'MA'))
```

**The error I"m getting is:**

> SELECT Name,ServiceAccountAssociation__r.Name
>               ^
>   *ERROR at Row:1:Column:13 Didn't understand relationship 'ServiceAccountAssociation__r' in field path. If you are attempting to
>   use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the
>   custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe
>   call for the appropriate names.*

The relationship is as follows:

**Accounts are related to Service__c (custom object) via the ServiceAccountAssociation__c custom object. There is a master-detail relationship called Service__c on the ServiceAccountAssociation object which connects Service to Account.**

I've looked at various salesforce documentation and am getting really lost...

Comment: SELECT Name, ServiceAccountAssociations__r.Name
             ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:14
Didn't understand relationship 'ServiceAccountAssociations__r' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: Line: 1, Column: 32
serviceaccountassociation__c is not a field of Account

Comment: There is a custom object ServiceAccountAssociations that joins the Account and Services object together

Comment: There isn't a field on the Account record that hosts that information. Did I build it wrong?

Comment: You can add a `Roll Up Summary` field on `Account` if `ServiceAccountAssociation__c` has a `Master-Detail` relationship to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Recommended - Roll Up Summary

If you have a `Master-Detail` relationship from `ServiceAccountAssociation__c` to `Account`, you can create a `Service_Count__c` roll up summary. Once you create the field, `Select Roll-Up Type` > `COUNT`. Then you can query `Account` directly without needing any cross-object `SOQL`.

```
SELECT Name FROM Account
WHERE Service_Count__c > 0
AND BillingState = 'MA'
```

## Alternative - Using Apex

### SubQuery

If you are using a junction, you likely have a relationship FROM `ServiceAccountAssociation__c` TO `Account`.

You want to find the child relationship, which you can do as follows:

```
DescribeSObjectResult describe = SObjectType.Account;
for (ChildRelationship relationship : describe.getChildRelationships())
{
    if (relationship.getChildSObject() == PermissionSetAssignment.SObjectType)
        system.debug(relationship.getRelationshipName());
}
```

Assuming it were `ServiceAccountAssociations__r`, you could do a sub-query:

```
SELECT Name, (SELECT Service__c, Service__r.Name FROM ServiceAccountAssociations__r)
FROM Account WHERE ...
```

### Aggregates

You may need to query the junction table itself if you want to figure out which `Accounts` are tied to any `Service__c` Try to describe the lookup field from `ServiceAccountAssociation__c` to `Account` and get its relationship name. Assuming the field is also called `Account__c`:

```
DescribeFieldResult describe = ServiceAccountAssociation__c.Account__c.getDescribe();
system.debug(describe.getRelationshipName());
```

Assuming it is `Account__r`, you could make queries against the junction table.

```
List<AggregateResult> junctionAggregates = [
    SELECT COUNT(Id) records, Account__c FROM ServiceAccountAssociation__c
    WHERE Account__r.BillingState = 'MA'
    GROUP BY Account__c
    HAVING COUNT(Id) > 0
];
```

Take a look at how the [HAVING](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_having.htm) clause works.

### Tying It Together

You can use the two above queries together to list all `Service` names associated to an `Account`:

```
Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
for (AggregateResult aggregate : /*aggregateQuery*/)
    accountIds.add(aggregate.get('Account__c'));
List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Name, /*subquery*/ FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accountIds];
```